Why did Rio Morales say, "De-escalated that one"?
At a dining table scene in Spider-Man Into the Spider-Verse (2018) Alternate Universe Cut, Cop Jefferson Davis warns his son Miles to stop creating graffiti or face arrest under code 1029-G. Miles retorts, questioning if Jeff has nothing better to do than arrest his own son for making art, and sarcastically asks if Jeff is the "fun police". Jeff affirms, humorously declaring himself the commissioner of the fun police:

Miles: Well maybe I'll just save the fun for when I quit school
and I move in with Uncle Aaron.
Miles leaves the dining table:
Rio Morales: De-escalated that one.




Why did Rio Morales say, "De-escalated that one" ?

Are you referring to this deleted scene? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKE5VONBMzA

@Valorum Thanks for finding the clip, I added to this question.

It’s not clear from the question what it is you find confusing about the line. Are you asking what “de-escalated” means? Are you wondering why she seems to be describing the opposite of what happened? Is there something else confusing you?

@ToddWilcox Are you wondering why she seems to be describing the opposite of what happened?  YES

Do you know what sarcasm is and didn’t realize it was sarcasm or are you not sure what sarcasm is?

It seems to be Rio's sarcastic congratulations to Jeff about his  failure.
Jeff tried to lower the tension between himself and his son (in other words to de-escalate the situation) with a joking admission of being the fun police, but it didn't work at all, so Rio is sarcastically congratulating her husband on his 'success'.

Rio is the mom. She’s sarcastically criticizing the dad (Jefferson) for handling the situation poorly.

Doh! Thank you for that

It's also significant that there's been a lot of talk lately about the job of the police rightly being to de-escalate tense situations, while some police have gotten in trouble for doing the reverse.  Since Jeff is an actual policeman, this sort of vocabulary would likely be in regular use in his workplace, and could spill over into his home life as well.

@DarrelHoffman - her comment appears to be a callback to an earlier scene, presumably one where he talks about de-escalating situations as part of his job. The reason the joke doesn't make any sense is because we are only seeing the punchline.
